# Mocking static void method with parameters using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I have class name called "EmailService.java"

```
public class EmailService {
  public static void send(String emailFrom, List<String> emailTo, String subject, String message) {
    MessageBuilder builder = Email.createMessageBuilder();
    builder.addFrom(emailFrom);
    builder.addTo(emailTo);
    builder.addSubject(subject);
    builder.addMessage(message);
    
    //builder.build() returns MimeMessage object
    Email.send(builder.build());
  }
}
```

I need mock the above "Email.send(builder.build());" line. So, my test class as like below...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({EmailService.class, Email.class, MimeMessage.class, MessageBuilder.class})
public class EmailServiceTest {
  
  private EmailService emailService;
  private Mimemessage message;
  private MessageBuilder builder;
  
  @Test
  public void testSend() throws Exception {
    mockStatic(Email.class);
    mockStatic(MimeMessage.class);
    
    message = Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class);
    builder = Mockito.spy(MessageBuilder.class);

    //Some line of code to prepare other mock data

    Mockito.when(builder.build()).thenReturn(message);
    
    PowerMockito.doNothing().doThrow(EmailException.class).when(Email.class);
    Email.send(message);
  }
}
```

If I have tried to apply like above way to mock the static void method with parameters using mockito, then I am facing Runtime Exception like below.

> org.mockito.exceptions.missusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:      Unfinished stubbing detected here:       -->
> PowerMockito.doNothing().doThrow(EmailException.class).when(Email.class);
> E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.

But,
If I have tried to mock like other way for static void method with parameters as like below.

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().doThrow(EmailException.class).when(Email.class, "send", Mockito.any(MimeMessage.class));
```

then I am getting compile time error like below.

> The method when(T) in the type Stubber is not applicable for the
> arguments (Class<Email>, String, Mockito.any(MimeMessage.class))

How to mock the static void method with parameters?

I am using below version jars for mocking.

- powermock-module-junit4: 1.7.4
- powermock-api-mockito2: 1.7.4

Comment: Probably many people would advise you to use instance methods instead of static ones. Having said that the error looks like Email's send method is not void but returns something so instead of doing 'doNothing()' the framework is probably expecting you to 'doReturn' something.

Comment: No, the Email.send is static void method only. Here is the method signature...

     public static void send(MimeMessage message) throws EmailException {